# Strange svn checkout error

Tags: svn

Has anyone had this unusual(recurring) experience before? I'm trying to check out the project from svn repository and I get this error :

> Checkout error; The file or directory
>   is corrupted and unreadable.
>       svn: Can't move 'C:\workspace\project.1267011912396.svn\tmp\entries'
>   to
>   'C:\workspace\project.1267011912396.svn\entries':
>   The file or directory is corrupted and
>   unreadable.

I previously tried it multiple times and it just checked out the project but now I've done it like 15 times and get the same error, what can I do ?

Comment: Stupid thing to check: Is there any free space on your drive? Is your drive about to fail (check SMART status)?

Comment: @Tadeusz A. Kadłubowski sure I do, lol .. although sometimes simplest things can be solution, but its not the case now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known bug in Windows 7, slated to be fixed in SP 1.

http://subversion.wandisco.com/blogs/windows-7-bogus-errorfilecorrupt-error-.html

Comment: @Matt McHenry how come other people don't get it just me ?

Comment: First, it's only on Windows 7, not Vista or XP.  Also, my understanding is that it can be exacerbated by other processes accessing Subversion's temp files at the same time as SVN itself.  So if you're running indexing service (for windows search), or a virus scanner, or even just have an explorer window open showing the SVN working copy, you'll tend to see it more often.  But none of those programs is actually the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

Create a backup of the whole directory structure (just in case you make more damage) and try running svn cleanup.

Comment: I'm using eclipse to checkout projects , how can I do that ?

Comment: @Gandalf: that's a material for another question. I have no idea.

Comment: @Gandalf Right-click project then select Team -> Cleanup

Comment: @Alexandre Jasmin will this affect in any way my project on repository?

Comment: @Gandalf Cleanup is something you do on a woking copy. If you're unable to checkout the project in the first place. It's not going to help.